# Add tags to long page that is broken up into subpages?

Tags: pages, pagination, tags

I have a long document that I am  publishing as a page and splitting into sub-pages using page breaks `<!--nextpage-->`.

I am trying  to find out if it is possible somehow to add tags to these sub-pages.

I can't seem to find a plugin or a tutorial out there on this subject.

Any help?

Comment: Please post your code. I don't that pagination should necessarily effect the tag display. It has something to do with your particular theme code.

Comment: I don't have any code. I just have a page into which I have inserted <!--nextpage--> which breaks the page up into sub-pages. I would like to add specific tags to these subpages.

Comment: Yes, you do have code. If you didn't the site wouldn't work. It is probably in `index.php` or `single.php`. If you tell me the URL for the problem page I might be able to tell you exactly.

Comment: I just have a default install of wordpress with no additional code added yet. I was hoping to simply add a plugin or some code snippets to functions.php to add the tags functionality.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Twenty Eleven right now.

Comment: [The code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/content-single.php) looks OK to me. Does your site have active tags? And are they assigned to posts?

Comment: Yes, to posts. but I am publishing my document as a PAGE. So I need somehow to add tagging to pages and assign them to my sub-pages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add tag support to your Pages.

```
function page_tags() {
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tags','pages'); // adds tag support
   add_meta_box('tagsdiv-page_tag','tags','post_tags_meta_box','page','side','low'); // adds the meta box itself
}
add_action('admin_init','page_tags');
```

You still won't see tags anywhere. You can move the meta box around using the 'side' and 'low' parameters. See the link below.

Now look in TwentyEleven's `content-single.php` and find the `get_the_tag_list` line. That is the part you want. You need to edit `content-page.php` to look like ...

```
<footer class="entry-meta">
    <?php echo get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

That should do it.

Be aware that editing a default theme is dangerous. It will be overwritten when you update. You should be creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: Thanks. But will this allow me to tag sub-pages created by using the <!--nextpage--> tag? These have  the URL structure: www.mysite.com/mypage/1 , www.mysite.com/mypage/2 , www.mysite.com/mypage/3 , www.mysite.com/mypage/4 . From the dashboard they are all part of the same page. But they are separated on the frontend.

Comment: You want to individually tag subpages?

Comment: yes - I need to tag individual sub-pages

Comment: Each sub-page with different tags? There is nothing built in that will do that, and I don't think it is a simple hack. Tags apply to the post and a paginated post is still just one post.